# While loop to display multiple results

Tags: php, html, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

So basically, I have an HTML form that asks a user to select an option from a dropdown list. The list is populated with a mysql query, but also includes an additional option labeled as 'All.' If the users selects all I want it my PHP script to run a timecard for so and so and then underneath that do the same thing for the next employee, so on and so forth. So far, it works fine if you select just one person, but if you select all it says there are no results to display :/. Any help is appreciated.

```
if ($empfullname == 'All') {
    $query = "select fullname from ".$db_prefix."info order by fullname asc";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
} else {
    print timecard_html($empfullname, $local_timestamp_in_week);
}

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print timecard_html(stripslashes("".$row['empfullname'].""), $local_timestamp_in_week);

}
```

Also, I know mysql is depreciated, but that is what I know and I am just trying to make it work with this. Thanks.

Comment: http://codular.com/php-mysqli.
Bookmark this page for your next project. I found the article really helpful when I was switching from mysql to mysqli

Comment: "I know it's deprecated (and maybe even suffers from SQL injection) but I'm going to use it anyway" That's a sad state.

Comment: Why do you concatenate `""` to the beginning and end of `$row['empfullname']`? I see this idiom from lots of newbies, where does it come from?

Comment: @JuanMendes He substituting into a table name, so he couldn't use a parameter even if he were using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Now, something looks off in your code. When doing your select statement, you are selecting 'fullname'. But when printing, you are using 'empfullname'. Kindly correct this first.